# Jaxb json conversion broken while moving from Jersey1.x to Jersey 2.x

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey-2.0

Please find the below example which was working as expected with Jersey 1.x with Jackson 1.x, but after migrating to Jersey 2.x and Jackson 2.x I am getting xml in json output.

```
 {
    "property": [{
        "attribs": ["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<name>layoutType</name>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<display>Layout Type</display>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<type>COMBO</type>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<align>left</align>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<items>1 X 2,2 X 1,2 X 2</items>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<order>1</order>"]
    }, {
        "attribs": ["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<name>chartTitle</name>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<display>Chart Title</display>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<type>TEXT</type>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>\n<order>2</order>"]
    }]
}
```

Code:-

XML Input (attributes.xml):

```
<configuration>
                            <property>
                                <name>layoutType</name>
                                <display>Layout Type</display>
                                <type>COMBO</type>
                                <align>left</align>
                                <items>1 X 2,2 X 1,2 X 2</items>
                                <order>1</order>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>chartTitle</name>
                                <display>Chart Title</display>
                                <type>TEXT</type>
                                <order>2</order>`enter code here`
                            </property>
                        </configuration>
```

JAXB Models:

```
                @XmlRootElement(name = "configuration")
                public class ConfigModel {

                    private List<PropertyModel> properties;

                    public ConfigModel () {
                    }

                    @XmlElement(name = "property")
                    public List<PropertyModel> getProperties() {
                        return properties;
                    }

                    public void setProperties(List<PropertyModel> properties) {
                        this.properties = properties;
                    }
                }

            @XmlRootElement
            public class PropertyModel{
                private List<Object> attribs;

                public PropertyModel() {
                }

                @XmlAnyElement
                public List<Object> getAttribs() {
                    return attribs;
                }

                public void setAttribs(List<Object> attribs) {
                    this.attribs = attribs;
                }
            }
```

REST API:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ConfigModel getAttributes() {
        ChartAttributeModel model = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ConfigModel .class);
            model = (ConfigModel ) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("attributes.xml"));
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
     {
        "property": [{
            "name": "layoutType",
            "display": "Layout Type",
            "type": "COMBO",
            "align": "left",
            "items": "1 X 2,2 X 1,2 X 2",
            "order": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "chartTitle",
            "display": "Chart Title",
            "type": "TEXT",
            "order": "2"
        }]
     }
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think Jackson is the problem. Look at the contents of all the `attrs`. It's just plain strings. What do you expect Jackson to do with that a list of Strings? You're getting the correct result. Given what is provided to Jackson. You need to figure out why JAXB is converting those properties to complete XML documents. My guess would be it doesn't know what to do with the `Object` generic type of the `List`.

Comment: While unmarshalling JAXB is creating ElementNSImpl objects for attribs. I was expecting json provider should generate required output.